# How to get each one of the objects from an array which includes three objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I put three arrays in an object, and I want to get each one of them to set the value, and I try `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){` to traverse it, it gets the value of an object, but I can not get the third level of the item.

And also, I try `const iterate = (obj)`, it does not work well.

Whether the iterate function can get the item then set the value or use .forEach to get it.

[The browser search tool](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/397040-%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2%E6%89%A9%E5%B1%95%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7/code)

```
var iconsData = {
   iconArraya: [
        {
            name: 'bilibili',
            image:'https://i.ibb.co/R9HMTyR/1-5.png',
            host: ['www.bilibili.com'],
            popup: function (text) {
                open('https://search.bilibili.com/live?keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(text));
            }
        }
    ],
    iconArrayb: [
        {
            name: 'open',
            image:'https://i.ibb.co/R9HMTyR/1-5.png',
            host: [''],
            popup: function (text) {
                if(text.indexOf("http://")==0||text.indexOf("https://")==0)
                window.open(text, "_blank");
                else window.open("http://"+text, "_blank");
            }
        }
    ],
    iconArrayc: [
        {
            name: 'copy',
            image:'https://i.ibb.co/R9HMTyR/1-5.png',
            host: [''],
            popup: function (text) {
                if(text.indexOf("http://")==0||text.indexOf("https://")==0)
                window.open(text, "_blank");
                else window.open("http://"+text, "_blank");
            }
        }
    ],

    hostCustomMap: {}
    }

    Object.keys(iconsData).forEach((key, index) => {
        Object.keys(iconsData[key]).forEach((keya, index) => {   
            iconsData[key][keya].host.forEach(function (host) {     // The console shows an Error
                iconsData.hostCustomMap[host] = iconsData[key][keya].custom;
            });
        });
   });

    var text = GM_getValue('search');
    if (text && window.location.host in iconsData.hostCustomMap) {
        keyword.beforeCustom(iconsData.hostCustomMap[window.location.host]);
    }
    var iconArray =
    {
        icona: document.createElement('div'),
        iconb: document.createElement('div'),
        iconc: document.createElement('div')
    }

    Object.keys(iconsData).forEach((key, indexa) => {
       Object.keys(iconsData[key]).forEach((keya, indexb) => {
           Object.keys(iconsData[key][keya]).forEach(function (obj) {
               var img = document.createElement('img');
               img.setAttribute('src', obj.image);
               img.setAttribute('alt', obj.name);
               img.setAttribute('title', obj.name);
               img.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
               keyword.beforePopup(obj.popup);
           });
           img.setAttribute('style', '' +
               'cursor:pointer!important;' +
               'display:inline-block!important;' +
               'width:22px!important;' +
               'height:22px!important;' +
               'border:0!important;' +
               'background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1)!important;' +
               'padding:0!important;' +
               'margin:0!important;' +
               'margin-right:5px!important;' +
               '');
           Object.keys(iconArray).forEach((keyb, indexc) => {
               if(indexc = indexa){
                   iconArray[keyb].appendChild(img);
                   console.log(indexc,indexa)
               }
           });
           });
        });
      });

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(iconArray).forEach(function(key){
        iconArray[key].setAttribute('style', '' +
            'display:none!important;' +
            'position:absolute!important;' +
            'padding:0!important;' +
            'margin:0!important;' +
            'font-size:13px!important;' +
            'text-align:left!important;' +
            'border:0!important;' +
            'background:transparent!important;' +
            'z-index:2147483647!important;' +
            '');
    });

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(iconArray).forEach(function(key){
        document.documentElement.appendChild(iconArray[key]);
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        if (e.target == iconArray || (e.target.parentNode && e.target.parentNode == iconArray)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function () {
        if (!window.getSelection().toString().trim()) {
            iconArray.icona.style.display = 'none';
            iconArray.iconb.style.display = 'none';
            iconArray.iconc.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        if (e.target == iconArray || (e.target.parentNode && e.target.parentNode == iconArray)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        var text = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
        var url = text.match(/(https?:\/\/(\w[\w-]*\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?!\w)(:\d+)?(\/([\x21-\x7e]*[\w\/=])?)?|(\w[\w-]*\.)+(com|cn|org|net|info|tv|cc|gov|edu)(?!\w)(:\d+)?(\/([\x21-\x7e]*[\w\/=])?)?)/i);
        if (url && iconArray.iconb.style.display == 'none') {
            iconArray.iconb.style.top = e.pageY +40 + 'px';
            if(e.pageX -70<10)
                iconArray.iconb.style.left='10px';
            else
                iconArray.iconb.style.left = e.pageX -70 + 'px';
            iconArray.iconb.style.display = 'block';
        } else if (text.length >= 30) {
            iconArray.iconc.style.top = e.pageY +40 + 'px';
           if(e.pageX -70<10)
               iconArray.iconc.style.left='10px';
           else
               iconArray.iconc.style.left = e.pageX -70 + 'px';
           iconArray.iconc.style.display = 'block';
        } else if (!text) {
            iconArray.icona.style.display = 'none';
            iconArray.iconb.style.display = 'none';
            iconArray.iconc.style.display = 'none';
        } else if(text && iconArray.icona.style.display == 'none'){
           iconArray.icona.style.top = e.pageY +40 + 'px';
           if(e.pageX -70<10)
               iconArray.icona.style.left='10px';
           else
               iconArray.icona.style.left = e.pageX -70 + 'px';
           iconArray.icona.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you pinpoint the exact data structure you're trying to access, and the exact output you'd like from it? There seems to be a lot of arbitrary code in your post. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys(object)` return an array of property names of the provided object and in your case it will return `[iconArraya,iconArrayb,iconArrayc]` if want to do it this way you'll have reference the object i.e for each value in the array you need to do this `object[value]` `by the way this is called bracket notation you can search it if you're unfamiliar it the same using a dot like object.value`
here's how ===

```
[iconArraya,iconArrayb,iconArrayc].forEach(property=>{
  object[property];
 })
```

you can also access the values by using `Object.values(object)`
here is how ===

```
Object.values(object).forEach(value=>{
 //here you don't have to reference the object you have direct access to the 
 value
})
```

or use a for...in loop and since a for...in loop gives you access to the property you will also have to reference the object here's how ===

```
for(property in object){
   object[property];
 // you can do whatever you want with the values even change them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because your code is trying to iterate over hostCustomMap with .forEach() which isn't what you want to do.

Use a constructor check to make sure the property is an array:

```
Object.keys(iconsData).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (iconsData[key].constructor==Array) {
        Object.keys(iconsData[key]).forEach((keya, index) => {
            iconsData[key][keya].host.forEach(function (host) {     // The console shows an Error
                iconsData.hostCustomMap[host] = iconsData[key][keya].custom;
            });
        });
    }
});
```