# How to create an Object that includes three node elements and sets the same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For the following code, I do not want to repeat it three times and it is better than ignore the keys as icona,iconb,iconc.

In another post [How to get each one of the objects from an array which includes three objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65239905/how-to-get-each-one-of-the-objects-from-an-array-which-includes-three-objects), I involve three Objects in an array, and here I want just create an object that includes the same three node elements.

```
var iconArray =
    {
        icona: document.createElement('div'),
        iconb: document.createElement('div'),
        iconc: document.createElement('div')
    }
```

By the way, in order to match the index of two Objects to set value, as the following code from that post, so if the 'iconsData' Object includes three Arrays, the 'iconArray' Object includes three node elements, or maybe both include four or five elements.

```
Object.keys(iconsData).forEach(function(value, indexa) {
           iconsData[value].forEach(function (obj,indexb) {
               Object.values(iconArray).forEach(function(keyc, indexc) {
                   var img = document.createElement('img');
                   if(indexc === indexa){
                       img.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
                           keyword.beforePopup(obj.popup);
                       });
                       img.setAttribute('style', '' +
                                        'cursor:pointer!important;' +
                                        'display:inline-block!important;'  +
                                        '');

                       keyc.appendChild(img);

                   }
               });
           });
    });
```

Comment: define 'make it simple' it seems to me that it's as simple as it gets, unless you mean make it dynamic / do not repeat the createElement code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var element = document.createElement('div')
var iconArray =
    {
        icona: element,
        iconb: element,
        iconc: element
    }
```

Comment: aha, it seems simple, and if I delete the keys icona,iconb,iconc, how to know there are three elements in the Object?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean but you can could the number of keys in an object with `Object.keys(iconArray).length`

Comment: Sure, and is this right in the Object? `var iconArray = { element, element, element }`

Comment: that would give you `var iconArray = { element: element }` - not sure if that is what you want?

Comment: @lyscop can you please clarify why you need to 3 keys of an object set to a single element? Do you need an object or an Array?

Comment: @adiga Sorry, I ask more requirement instead of details, Lrwin's answer achieve the desired effect, and for more, I just want to know whether the keys icona,iconb,iconc can delete, and the total length can match the 'iconsData' Object mentioned in the updated content.

Comment: @JonathanIrwin Bro, can you give me more suggestions to it instead of the keys icona,iconb,iconc with the details for that will use in nowhere.